# «В данном случае» в самом конце

Tags: пунктуация

Помогите, пожалуйста, определиться, нужна ли запятая: 
«Он питается сильными эмоциями. Ненавистью(,) в данном случае». 
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Он питается сильными эмоциями. НЕнавистью, (как) в данном случае.***

Сравнить: *ненавистью, например.*

При обособлении обстоятельственный оборот уточняет вид сильных эмоций, произношение с паузой.

Вариант без обособления тоже возможен, но тогда ударение будет падать на конечное слово фразы: ***Ненавистью в данном слУчае.***
Ключевое слово ***ненависть*** не будет выделено.

Answer (score 1):

Предлагаю более удобопонятную морфу Вашему предложению:
*Он питается сильными эмоциям. В данном случае — ненавистью.*

Comment: Дать совет — это нормально. После ответа.

Comment: Именно ***морфу***?!

Comment: Уважаемый Бегемот, а что, собственно, Вас смущает?

Answer (score -1):

Там нельзя ставить запятую. `В случае` вводным являться не может, а `в данном случае` тем более.

Это равносильно `в этом случае`.

Но можно поставить тире, чтобы подчеркнуть, что это именно в данном случае.